# ReactJS & Django axios.post (403 error code)

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I keep getting error code 403 (Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/) even after following some responses on this kind of questions.

This is my code:

JS

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFTOKEN';
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';

class App extends Component {
    postHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => alert(error));
    };
}
```

settings.py

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = 'http://localhost:3000',
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello!")
```

Anything else is set as defaults from create-react-app and django-admin startproject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be added in order to work:

JS

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

settings.py

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

# Create your views here.
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello!")
```